# HTML5 IFRAME not working in Safari, Chrome & FireFox

Tags: html, iframe

I got an HTML5 page with an iframe which the content is not in HTML5 doc type. The html content on the iframe is not displaying when browsing it in (Safari, FireFox and Chrome). However, the content is displaying correctly in IE.

```
<iframe src="82_Monopolization%20Under%20Antitrust%20Laws._files/slide0001.html" id="ifrm_slide" width="100%" height="100%" align="center"></iframe>
```

Why is the iframe is showing a link [here] instead of rendering the html depending on the src? It is only happening when the browser is not IE.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: When it works in IE it's usually not a good sign.